# How do you pass a variable from grail's Controller to gsp file via Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

I am trying to display an alert message saying congratulations after the user inputed some data. The thing is that I validate the input in my controller. If there is an error, I pass the appropriate variables to my view to hightlight the fields that are incorrect I do not know how to display the congratulations alert box though. This is what I have tried but it does not work. Any help? Thanks!

```
//In my ImplementNewPixel.gsp
<script>
         $.ajax({
                success:function(result){
                    if(result.message != null && result.message != ""){
                        alert(result.message);
                    }
                }
            });      
</script>

//In my actionsController:
def validate = {

    String message = ""

    if(Info is not valid){
       //return appropriate info to highlight incorrect textfields
    }

    else{
       message = "Congratulations your tracking pixel has been created and added!" as JSON
    }

    return [message: message, OtherStuff: OtherStuffThatIPassToMyGSP]
}
```

This not my exact code. I only included the main things that involve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using ajax, you need to return the model in something your javascript library understands. You appear to be using jQuery which will automatically determine the data type by the response's content-type.

```
class MyController {
    def validate() {
        return [message: "hello there"] as JSON
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm im not sure if this will work with my code because I am passing other stuff as well to my gsp view and they should not be passed in as  JSON because my view will see my other variables as a null object.

Comment: You should split the normal action and the Ajax action apart.

Answer (score 1):

Just return your message variable in the model of your controller action (see http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#modelsAndViews), like :

```
return [message : message]
```

...and use ${message} in your gsp to retrieve its value, like this :

```
alert("${message}")
```

Comment: He's using ajax so this doesn't apply.

Comment: Haha sorry about the confusing title. I forgot to mention ajax in it.

Comment: I gave up and went with this method so that actually helped me out. Thanks!